# SQL - Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert, unique-constraint

I am trying to find the solution for the below query:

There are declared tables `@Country` and `@WHO` (World Health Organization).

Insert all possibles countries from table `@Country` into table `@WHO`.

The code for the tables is:

```
DECLARE @Country TABLE 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Capital NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Country (Name, Capital) 
VALUES ('China', 'Beijing'), ('Japan', 'Tokyo'), 
       ('India', 'New Delhi'), ('South Korea', 'Seoul')

DECLARE @WHO TABLE
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Country NVARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
)

INSERT INTO @WHO (Country) 
VALUES ('Japan'), ('South Korea')
```

The code that I started looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO @WHO (w.Country)
    SELECT DISTINCT c.Name
    FROM @Country c

SELECT w.Country 
FROM @WHO w 
ORDER BY w.Country
```

The final result should be a table that contains:

```
China
India
Japan
South Korea
```

I know this is probably an easy one but I cannot seem to find a solution.

What am I missing out from my code? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO @WHO (w.Country)
SELECT DISTINCT c.Name
FROM @Country c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @WHO w WHERE w.Country = c.Name)
```

A (possibly overkill) alternative is the `MERGE` syntax:

```
MERGE INTO @WHO w
USING (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM @Country) c
ON (c.Name = w.Country)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (Country) VALUES(c.Country)
```

Comment: It is working now, with only one amendment: (SELECT 1 FROM @WHO w WHERE w.Country= c.Name). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The expected query of the task would be

```
INSERT INTO @WHO (Country)
SELECT
    c.Name
FROM @Country c
LEFT JOIN @WHO w ON w.Country = c.Name
WHERE w.Id IS NULL
```

though I like the 'not exists' version as more universal